# How do I group and then count a NSSet?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsset

How do I tackle grouping the records in a Core Data entity and then counting them so I can find the group with the highest count?

I have a 'set' which has many 'legs' each of which has one 'winner'. The question I am trying to answer is: Who has won the most legs.

Help is appreciated. Oh, and happy new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the set and count the 'legs' for each 'winner'. Save the leg-counts in a dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary* legCount = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSNumber* count;
for (leg in legsSet) {
    id winner = [leg objectForKey:@"winner"]; // assumes leg is a dictionary
    if (count = [legCount objectForKey:winner]) {
        [legCount setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[count intValue]+1] forKey:winner];
    } else {
        [legCount setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:winner];
    }
}
```

Now you need to find the key in the new dictionary with the highest value.

```
id winner = [[legCount keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 intValue] > [obj2 intValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 intValue] < [obj2 intValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}] lastObject];
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm having trouble getting the first bit to work. As my leg is a set i changed the id winner line to : id winner = [leg valueForKey:@"winner"]; but it crashes on the else line with: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Players copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d80180'. Also what is the "if (count = [legCount objectForKey:winner])" trying to do?

Comment: I haven't tested the code myself. Check if the object winner is a valid object (must not be nil). The if-line checks if the key is already set, if no sets its value to 1 and if yes, increments the value by 1. Oh.. and I just noticed some errors in my code... will fix it.

Comment: winner is valid. Each leg has a winner, but it throws up the above error.

Comment: I think this isn't working because 'leg' is a NSSet, but it doesn't seem enough to just change id winner = [leg objectForKey:@"winner"] to id winner = [leg valueForKey:@"winner"]; Is there a different approach I need to take? or do all the legs need to be added to a dictionary? and if so how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Ah, I just needed to take the objectID and put that into the dictionary.